# How to display user Information in an action bar, in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my app, I want to put the user profile image in an `ImageView` as well as the user name next to it, displayed on the right side of the action bar.

Can any one help me, how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create custom layout for action bar and then assign this custom layout to action bar

```
 ActionBar actionBar = supportActionBar;
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#363636")));
    //   actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_side_menu));
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(//Center the textview in the ActionBar !
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Gravity.CENTER);
    View viewActionBar = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.general_top_header, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(viewActionBar, params);

    TextView _Header_Text_View = (TextView) viewActionBar.findViewById(R.id.header_Name);
    _Header_Text_View.setText("" + header_Text);
    final ImageView back_Button = (ImageView) viewActionBar.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    back_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {




        }
    });
```

and your general_top_header.xml will be like

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Back_And_Bok_mark_button_Custome_Background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/top_header_color"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/general_back_arrow_selector" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="header"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:textSize="20dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
<!--<View-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/toolbar_shadow"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="3dp"-->
    <!--android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />-->
```

and in your style use

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
</style>
```

do not forgot to extend your activity with ActionBarActivity

```
public class Your_Activity extends ActionBarActivity{
}
```

Comment: @AnimeshJena Np Have a nice Day.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to change layout for header use this. It is version with Universal Image Loader ([GitHub](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)). But if you don't want this lib, bottom you have another code with pure bitmap file.

After this change your app will be look like this.

[image]

```
public void changeAvatarAndTitle(String LOGIN, String AVATARURL){
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        String login = LOGIN;
        String urlOfAvatr = AVATARURL;
        try {
            if (imageLoader != null)
                imageLoader.loadImage(urlOfAvatar, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
                        Bitmap b = loadedImage;
                        double density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                        if (density >= 4.0) {
                            //"xxxhdpi";
                            b = Global.getResizedBitmap(b, 192, 192);
                        }
                        if (density >= 3.0 && density < 4.0) {
                            //xxhdpi
                            b = Global.getResizedBitmap(b, 144, 144);
                        }
                        if (density >= 2.0) {
                            //xhdpi
                            b = Global.getResizedBitmap(b, 96, 96);
                        }
                        if (density >= 1.5 && density < 2.0) {
                            //hdpi
                            b = Global.getResizedBitmap(b, 72, 72);
                        }
                        if (density >= 1.0 && density < 1.5) {
                            //mdpi
                            b = Global.getResizedBitmap(b, 48, 48);
                        }

                        b = Global.getRoundedCornerBitmap(b, 100);

                        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b);

                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 14) {
                            actionBar.setLogo(d);
                        }
                    }
                });
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setTitle(" " + login);
            actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

version without Universal Image Loader from Internet.

```
public void changeAvatarAndTitle(String LOGIN, String AVATARURL, Bitmap loadedImage){
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        String login = LOGIN;
        String urlOfAvatr = AVATARURL;
        Bitmap b = loadedImage;
        double density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        if (density >= 4.0) {
            //"xxxhdpi";
            b = Global.getResizedBitmap(b, 192, 192);
        }
        if (density >= 3.0 && density < 4.0) {
            //xxhdpi
            b = Global.getResizedBitmap(b, 144, 144);
        }
        if (density >= 2.0) {
            //xhdpi
            b = Global.getResizedBitmap(b, 96, 96);
        }
        if (density >= 1.5 && density < 2.0) {
            //hdpi
            b = Global.getResizedBitmap(b, 72, 72);
        }
        if (density >= 1.0 && density < 1.5) {
            //mdpi
            b = Global.getResizedBitmap(b, 48, 48);
        }
        b = Global.getRoundedCornerBitmap(b, 100);
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 14) {
            actionBar.setLogo(d);
        }                   
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(" " + login);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    }
}


public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: what is this Global in it?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by simple way also.You can set the icon of 'ActionBar ' as the profile image and the title as the profile name.
However if you want more customization then using 'ToolBar' is better option.